# Rails i18n locale and regions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have the following problem, I'm using the standard i18n to translate to spanish all the website (:es), but now I want to change model label that depends on regions and not only language.

So I want to use es-MX,es-AR,es-PA and so on but in the documentation it says that rails doesn't support regionalization.

Some examples of regionalization:
For some model labels I use: DNI (identity document) but in mexico the correct label is IFE.

So is there a way to add support for es-MX, es-AR and other regionalizations

Answer (score 0):

If you look here https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale then you will see that the regions you want are present here as separate languages. You can do what you want the same way. Just use each region as a separate language. Good luck !